# SQL Server clustered index creation in parallel

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I have two tables `T_A` and `T_B`.

- Both are empty.
- Both has clustered index on them.
- Recovery model is set to `SIMPLE`.
- The insert...select.. meets the requirements of minimal logging. See
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191244.aspx
- Both staging tables contains large amount of data.

I need to import data into them from staging tables.

If I perform the following T-SQL blocks individually, each takes 2 to 3 minutes to finish. The total time is about 5 to 6 minutes.

```
BEGIN TRAN
  INSERT INTO T_A WITH(TABLOCK) FROM SRC_A WITH(NOLOCK);
COMMIT TRAN

BEGIN TRAN
  INSERT INTO T_B WITH(TABLOCK) FROM SRC_B WITH(NOLOCK);
COMMIT TRAN
```

To make it faster I open two sessions in SMSS and execute the two blocks in parallel. To my surprise, each session takes about 10 to 12 minutes to finish. Together the total time is more than doubled. The `wait_type` shown is `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` which point to disk I/O bottleneck. What I don't understand is that even if the two sessions have to wait on each other for I/O it should not wait for that long. Can anyone help explain this?

My story has not ended here yet. Then I removed the clustered index on both table and ran the two blocks in parallel each in a different session. This time each takes about 1 minutes to finish. The total time is about 1 minutes since they are in parallel. Great! But the nightmare comes when I try to create clustered index back.

If I create the cluster index individually it takes 4 minutes each to finish. The total time is about 8 minutes. This defeated my purpose of improving performance.

Then I try to create clustered index on the two tables in parallel each on a different session. This time it is the worst: one takes 12 minutes to finish and the other takes 25 minutes to finish.

From my test result my best choice is back to square one: execute the two transactions sequentially with clustered index on the table.

Has anyone experienced similar situation and what is the best practice to make it faster?

Comment: I have nothing to back this up, but my guess would be that your first test case has the advantage of the I/O being sequential... meaning that the head on your disk isn't having to jump all over the place... and in all your other test cases the I/O is random, meaning that the head writes one block for one of your tables, then jumps to another spot on the disk to write a different block for the other table, and back and forth like that... which is why parallel execution is taking longer than sequential execution.

Comment: Does removing the WITH(TABLOCK) hint improve your parallel insert speed? Is the data in SRC_A and SRC_B likely to hit different or the same areas of the clustered index?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Removing WITH(TABLOCK) won't help because that will make the insert become fully logged. And the two tables are totally different. Their cluster key columns are totally different.

Comment: I incline to believe the parallel slowness is due to disk head jumping but didn't expect the cost is so huge. And I tried to google it but not much luck in finding a similar situation and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the clustered index after inserting the records SQL has to recreate this table in the background anyway so it would be faster to insert the records directly into the table with the clustered index already present.
Also disable any non clustered indexes while inserting and enable them afterwards again, creating indexes on a filled table is faster than updating them for each insert. Remember to set Max DOP option to 0 when creating indexes.

Bulk inserts are also a lot faster then insert into statement.
I use the 'SQL server import and export wizard' for copying large amounts of data and it seems to be way faster (the wizard uses bulk statements). If necessary you can try to find the statement this wizard uses and run it yourself.